# How to fetch heading and an image from specific link typed in textarea

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter(PHP) and I am trying to implement a "POST COMMENT" functionality. I want to ask that how to fetch the heading and an image from a specific link when you type that link in textarea.

```
$post=$_POST['post']; //post is the name of text area that contains link
$result=file_get_contents($post);
echo $result;
```

if I enter www.google.com in my textarea it takes me to that site, rather than returning me the main image and heading

Comment: you can use file_get_contents function

Comment: i have edited my question have a look at it

Comment: You can use CURL as well. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract Url from `$_POST['post']` content as you assuming it contains link
after that write a function to get html

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}
```

**Get Heading** :-

```
$html=getHTML("http://www.website.com",10);
 $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $html, $matches);
        if (!$res)
            return null;

// Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $matches[1]);
$title = trim($title);
echo $title;
```

Similarly you you can extract image from html content. Its depends on you how many images you need from html. If you need single image from html content then you can extract as above using preg_match. If you need multiple then you can use below solution.

Yoy can also use [SIMPLEHTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library to extract image like this:-

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$html=getHTML("http://www.website.com",10);
// Find all images on webpage
foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: it says undefined index 1, at $title=$match[1]

Comment: Pleasure to help you.